# Monte Carlo Localization example

Tags: localization, artificial-intelligence, robotics, montecarlo

I want to implement Monte Carlo Localization in a project I'm doing.  The first thing I did is I tried to implement it in a virtual robot navigating a 2D world.  Right now the program is really slow, doesn't work, and I'm making little progress.  So I'm wondering if anyone can point to an example of Monte Carlo Localization I can look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [AMCL](http://ros.org/wiki/amcl) driver that is part of ROS. That implements the Adaptive Monte Carlo Localization algorithm described in Probabilistic Robotics.

If you have any questions specific to that driver and how it works, the ROS community has a Q&A site at [ROS Answers](http://answers.ros.org). That would be a good forum for questions specific to that implementation.